# interstitial ad Admob, illegalStateException

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial, banner-ads

I implemented a structure to display interstitial Ads in my app, i declared interstitial Ad object in Application class so it can be accessed across the activities, Unfortunately i am getting `illegalStateException` on the line where i set ad unit id i.e `interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(addunitId)`. What could be the possible reason for this.

***Here is my Code***

**MyCustomApplication**

```
    public class MyCustomApplication extends Application {

    public InterstitialAd interstitialAd=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void initialAdsSetUp() {

        if (interstitialAd == null)
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                startLoadingAds();
            }

        });
        startLoadingAds();
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    void startLoadingAds() {
        if (!interstitialAd.isLoading() && !interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    void showAd() {
        if (interstitialAd != null)
            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }
    }
    //-----------------------------------

}
```

**Splash Screen**

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
private MyCustomApplication admobApp;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    admobApp = (MyCustomApplication) getApplication();
    admobApp.initialAdsSetUp();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

} //onCreate() closed

}
```

Comment: Follow the link: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

Comment: Did you initialised Mobile ads like    MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

Comment: yes i have tested with  MobileAds.initialize() too and results are the same. this exception occur for few numbers of users only.

Comment: Could you paste the logs.